# Showing data when a datagridview's cell is entered

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, sql-server-2008, datagridview

i have a datagridview like this :
[datagridviewMut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDSau.png)

I want to input data directly in datagridview. When I input nip 123456789123456789, I want data name out automatically from database... and I use a class for taking data from the database.. but it doesn't output the name..

this is my coding using visual basic:

```
Private Sub DgvUMutasi_CellEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DgvUMutasi.CellEnter
    Dim columnName As String = DgvUMutasi.Columns(DgvUMutasi.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DgvUMutasi.CurrentRow

    cp.P_NIP = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString

    If columnName = "NIP" And cp.KeypressID() = True Then
        row.Cells(1).Value = cp.P_Nama
    End If
End Sub
```

and this is the function of keypressID: (Edit: changed code layout)

```
    Public Function KeypressID() As Boolean  
    Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(StrConn)  
    Dim cmmd As New SqlCommand  
    Dim dreader As SqlDataReader  
    Dim SQL As String  

    SQL = "SP_SELECT_PEGAWAI"

    cnn.Open()
    cmmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, cnn)
    cmmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmmd.Parameters.Clear()
    cmmd.CommandText = SQL
    cmmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@P1", NIP))
    dreader = cmmd.ExecuteReader

    If dreader.Read = True Then
        Dim ImgByte() As Byte = dreader("Foto")
        Dim ImgStr As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ImgByte)
        Me.Foto = Image.FromStream(ImgStr)
        Me.Nama = dreader("Nama")
        Me.Jabatan = dreader("Jabatan")
        Me.Daerah = dreader("Daerah")
        Me.Tsk = dreader("Tsk_Jab")
        Me.PktPns = dreader("Pnk_Pns")
        Me.GolPns = dreader("Gol_Pns")
        Me.TmtPns = dreader("Tmt_Pns")
        Me.Pensiun = dreader("Pensiun")
        Return True
    Else
        Me.Foto = Nothing
        Me.Nama = ""
        Me.Jabatan = ""
        Me.Daerah = ""
        Me.Tsk = Date.Now
        Me.PktPns = ""
        Me.GolPns = ""
        Me.TmtPns = Date.Now
        Me.Pensiun = Date.Now
        Return False
    End If
    cnn.Close()
End Function
```

which part is wrong?

Comment: Try DgvUMutasi.Bind() after row.Cells(1).Value = cp.P_Nama

Comment: not working... anything else?

Comment: Put break point and see if this code row.Cells(1).Value = cp.P_Nama is beign hit?

Comment: (no condition) break always (currently 0)